# PostgreSQL. Как сформировать из JSON пары ключ-значение

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Таблица mytable:

| oid | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"id":"11","value":1205}{"id":"12","value":"dsns"},{"id":"13","value":null},{"id":"14","value":true}] |
| 20 | [{"id":"201","value":"sfen"}{"id":"202","value":";meekk"},{"id":"203","value":54948},{"id":"204","value":5892}] |

Нужно вытащить все пары значений id:value для каждого oid:

| oid | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 1205 |
| 1 | 12 | dsns |
| 1 | 13 | null |
| 1 | 14 | true |
| --- | -- | ---- |
| 20 | 204 | 5892 |

С json на "Вы". Как решить данную задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (oid INT, data JSON);
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1, '[{"id":"11","value":1205},{"id":"12","value":"dsns"},{"id":"13","value":null},{"id":"14","value":true}]'),
(20, '[{"id":"201","value":"sfen"},{"id":"202","value":";meekk"},{"id":"203","value":54948},{"id":"204","value":5892}]');
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| oid | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"id":"11","value":1205},{"id":"12","value":"dsns"},{"id":"13","value":null},{"id":"14","value":true}] |
| 20 | [{"id":"201","value":"sfen"},{"id":"202","value":";meekk"},{"id":"203","value":54948},{"id":"204","value":5892}] |

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT oid, JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TEXT(data)::JSON val
  FROM test 
  )
SELECT oid, val->>'id' id, val->>'value' value
FROM cte
```

| oid | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 1205 |
| 1 | 12 | dsns |
| 1 | 13 | *null* |
| 1 | 14 | true |
| 20 | 201 | sfen |
| 20 | 202 | ;meekk |
| 20 | 203 | 54948 |
| 20 | 204 | 5892 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZBwQgjPo)

Обращаю внимание - `true` в 4-й строке результата не константа TRUE, а обычная строка со значением `'true'`.

Comment: Согласен, кавычки не поставил

Comment: Спасибо! Всё получилось!